# Easily calculating and listing binary combinations

Tags: php, algorithm, binary, combinations

I have 5 bits and so 32 different combinations (of them).

Starting from

```
00000
```

and ending with

```
11111
```

Is there some way of quickly listing all possibilities? I could do it by hand, but I worry that I might miss one. I'm guessing some clever chap has written some algorithm and/or made a website, that can do this very easily. At least I hope so.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: It's actually PHP. There's five possible fail points in a form, so I thought I'd just pass the error as an integer, and then convert it to binary, and output the error message depending on which "bits" were flagged. It might be a really bad way to do what I want to do, but it sound efficient :-)

Comment: @Django - you'd be better off doing bitwise operations to determine which flags were set http://www.infernodevelopment.com/bitwise-and-flags

Comment: It might be efficient but "premature optimization is the root of all evil". First make the code easy to read and then, if necessary, optimize.

Comment: @Jonas, Yes, that's true, but I can't think of a way to do what I want to do without creating a mess of if statements. Surely that can't be the best way to begin?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing any code and not being familiar with PHP but how about passing the errors in some kind of collection?

Comment: Actually, using bitwise operations has proven to be extremely easy. I'm almost done with the error handling already. Thanks for trying to help, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby:

```
0b0000.upto(0b1111) {|n| puts n.to_s(2).rjust(4,"0")}
```

```
0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
0110
0111
1000
1001
1010
1011
1100
1101
1110
1111
```

Comment: This turned out to be the simplest solution. I just went to http://www.TryRuby.org and then typed in: 

0b00000.upto(0b11111){|n| puts n.to_s(2).rjust(5,"0")}

Answer (score 5):

This will put them all on the command line on Linux.

`echo {0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}`

Comment: Beautiful answer. Append `| tr ' ' '\n'` to get each number on a separate line.

Comment: If I had I access to Linux, this is undoubtedly what I would have done.

Answer (score 2):

Write a column with integer from 0 to 31, then write a second column with the binary equivalent of each integer side-by-side.

That way you will increase your chance not to miss a combination.

Answer (score 2):

Just count from 0 to 31 and output the digit in it's binary form.

Something like this should do:

```
public static String zeroPad(String str) {
    return "00000".substring(str.length()) + str;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        System.out.printf("%s%n", zeroPad(Integer.toBinaryString(i)));
}
```

Output:

```
00000
00001
00010
00011
...
11110
11111
```

Comment: Sure this will print out strings of length 5?

Comment: No, you would have to pad with zeros.

Answer (score 1):

for (int i = 0; i <31; i++)
  cout << ((i & 16) >> 4) << ((i & 8) >> 3) << ((i & 4) >> 2) 
       << ((i & 2) >> 1) << (i & 1) << endl;

Answer (score 0):

Unix:

```
echo {0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1} | xargs -n 1
```